# Blender FBX Import transform/axis

Tags: transforms, import

I have an FBX file exported from 3DS Max. Using an FBX viewer, this is the model.

[image]

While importing into Blender, these are my settings (default)

[image]

When imported into Blender, this is the model.

[image]

There are some issue with this import.

1. the transform for some of the object seem to be using the wrong axis system and perhaps also a wrong origin.
2. The model is squished (scaled non-uniformly on 1 single axis.

Am I doing something wrong?

Blender version: 2.77a

Comment: What other settings have you tried for the importer?  Especially the manual orientation.  Blender uses -Y forward and Z up.  Other programs use -Z forward and Y up.  If that doesn't help consider posting a link to the fbx.

Comment: @batFINGER 3ds max uses Z up