# How can I fix the default orientation of a model?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I downloaded a 3d motorbike from unity asset store. But its facing forward along -x-axis. All the parts are separate as children of a main object. I would like to fix it so that its facing along z-axis by default.  How can this be achieved in blender?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56304/problems-with-rotation-and-scale-importing-blender-object-to-unity-replicate-un and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51188/blender-fbx-import-transform-axis

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are importing a .fbx file but even if you are not these setting are available on some other format imports. Simply select the orientation before importing
[image]